# Uncovering how changes in feature importance impact label prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm using random forest and decision trees as classifiers and using feature_importance to rank which features impact the outcome the most. However, I'd like to go deeper and understand how the features impact classification. I.e. does an increase in the value of a particular feature drive the prediction more toward a "1" or a "0"? Is there any way to extract this type of information from sklearn classifiers?

Comment: In R you can generate partial Dependence Plots with the mlr package after having trained a random forest. I do not know if something like this is possible in Python.

The patterns could possibly also be more complex like e.g. quadratic relationship, so a simple number possibly is not enough.